# Different ways to click a hyper link programmatically?

Tags: javascript, c#, hyperlink

What are some other ways to programmatically click a text link on a page? The link does not have a ID and will not have one. 
example link will look like this:

```
<div unselectable="on" class="x-grid-cell-inner " style="text-align:left;">
<a href="file/files/now.pdf">Click Here</a>   
</div>
```

Here's one way I can do it but want to know more ways to click it.

```
var els = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    for (var i = 0, l = els.length; i < l; i++) 
    {
       var el = els[i];
       if (el.text === 'Click Here') 
       {
           el.click()
       }
    }
```

Comment: `The link does not have a ID and will not have one`  Why not?  That would make for the most efficient code.  Traversing the entire DOM tree is not efficient.  If your relevant <a> tag is contained in a more well defined region (e.g. a div with an ID or class), you can search only that part of the DOM.

Comment: @Eric J. but what if we have 10000 ids. Will it be better to give every of them an ID. And just think about it: **there will be 10000 variables in global scope**, since every element with _id_ creates _a variable in global scope_ with name of its _id_. Just write `window['comment-51311540']` in console and you will see _tr_ element with your comment! :D

Comment: @EricJ. updated post. Reason no ID is because it is auto generated link for downloading a file.

Comment: If you have 10000 ids I would carefully test your page design on the lowest end browser that you intend to support.  And it will still be far more efficient to use IDs than to scan a massive DOM.

Comment: `Reason no ID is because it is auto generated link for downloading a file`  Then autogenerate an ID too and either pass it into your JavaScript, or generate the relevant portion of the JavaScript as well.

Comment: I want to click it without a ID. if you don't have any other answers its ok.

Comment: @GrandMother do you know anything in advance about this link? Does it have a unique class name? unique href value? other than 'click here' text that is.

Comment: @Shahar no i do not.

Comment: Are you looking to click the link or download the linked to document?

Answer (score 0):

It can't have an id?  That would be the best route IMO.  Second best approaches:

2. Assign a class, and look up by class

or

3. Assign an id or class to the parent object, and look up the first "a" child

Comment: updated post. Reason no ID is because it is auto generated link for downloading a file.

Comment: Is it someone else's code generating the link?  For example, where you don't have or can't change the source code?   If so, the only route is probably to scan the entire document.

Comment: The code you posted should work, I think.  If it were me, I might not use javascript if I just wanted to download files listed in a webpage.  Command line tools like grep, sed, awk, wget, curl might also work.

Comment: @user1389596 well if the user were using a script lets say.... as a bookmarklet, they will avoid the Command Line. but if its just for the simple scraping it would be better just to use Command lin